# What does the "target" feature on editconfig used for in CQ5?

Tags: adobe, aem

[image]

What does the "Target" option do when clicked and what is its importance? When I click on it, it is simply deleting the component from that page. Can anybody let me know its importance and how to use/configure it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the part of the [Adobe Test & Target](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/integrating_with_adobe_marketing_cloud/test_and_target.html) integration. If you have this integration configured correctly, it *enables you to display different content to different visitors based on information known about that visitor*. More info can be found in the official [CQ docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/wcm/content-targeting.html).